# Add materials to copied object

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm very new to Blender and I'm watching Grant Abbitt's tutorial and it's so good but I got 1 bug. When I need to add a material to an object, this material goes to every object which i copied from the original!

I already tried to click on the object and set a custom material but still the same, i can't get two objects (copied) with a different material. Anyone can help?

This is the video i followed [Complete Beginners Guide to Blender 2.8 | Free Course | Part 4 | Materials](https://youtu.be/OFmKedu8r88?t=248), but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, you've copied the object using <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (duplicate linked), you should use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (duplicate object) instead so that the new object will have its own data.

*"duplicate linked"*

> is called a deep link. This will create a new object with all of its
> data linked to the original object.

See the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html#duplicate-linked).

Comment: This is work Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, Blender lets you associate a material with the Object, rather than its Mesh, even on a per-face basis, by selecting 'Object' in the dropdown in the lower right of the area illustrated below:

[image]

All these cubes are <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instances of one another:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make your object a single user with its own material
Go the 3d view header and use

Blender Object - Relations - Make single user
[image]
Object > Make Single User > Object & Data & Materials + Tex.